# Android Global Integer Not Working

Tags: android, variables, integer, global

I am making an android game and I am making a shop. I got to the global variable part and nothing seems to work. My problem is that when i go to level two, the app says it has stopped working and goes to the menu. I am a noob to programming so maybe i am not doing something right, but I need help. Here is my code for where all the shop integers are going to be:

```
public class Globals extends Application{

private int player_health=10;

   public int getData(){
     return this.player_health;
   }

   public void setData(int d){
     this.player_health=d;
   }

}
```

Part of the android manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".Globals"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.WorldSelect"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_world_select" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.LevelSelect"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_level_select" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.Store"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_store" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.LevelTwo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_level_two" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.CharacterSelect"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_character_select" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.hunter.pixeldeath.Integers"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_integers" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

And were I use the code that causes the problem ( I think):

```
Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
int player_health=g.getData();

atk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (enemy_health > 0){
                enemy_health = enemy_health - player_damage;
                enmh.setText("Enemy Health:" + enemy_health);

                player_health = player_health = enemy_damage;
                plrh.setText("Player Health " + player_health);


                } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

logcat:

```
    08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hunter.pixeldeath/com.hunter.pixeldeath.LevelTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at com.hunter.pixeldeath.LevelTwo.<init>(LevelTwo.java:21)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What cause "the app says it has stopped working" ?, could you post the LogCat?

Comment: You should post full LevelTwo class and point us what is code in line 21 of this :).

Comment: That is right. take a look at "at com.hunter.pixeldeath.LevelTwo.<init>(LevelTwo.java:21)"

Answer (score 0):

You have got a `NullPointerException` in LevelTwo.java in line 21, that happens when the `LevelTwo` instance is constructed. Look at this line to find out which variable could be `null` or use a debugger.

These lines from the stack trace tell you this:

```
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 23:59:19.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1525):     at com.hunter.pixeldeath.LevelTwo.<init>(LevelTwo.java:21)
```

Edit (after some more information from OP):

the error occurs in the second line (which is in the class constructor):

```
Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
int player_health=g.getData();
```

There is only one possibility to get a NPE here, namely that `g` is `null`. And `g` is `null` because the application is not yet set when the constructor is executed. The code should be moved to the `onCreate()` method of the activity.

Comment: line 21 is where i try to get the integer

Comment: I cut Globals g = (GLoabals... and int player_health=g.getData from line 21

Comment: I do this and then it gives me this error everywhere I use it: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable player_health inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: Then define the variable at class level but initialize it in `onCreate`.

Answer (score -1):

Make the Global Variable `player_health` a static variable. That is your code becomes

```
public class Globals extends Application{
   private static int player_health;

   public static int getData(){
     return this.player_health;
   }

   public static void setData(int d){
     this.player_health=d;
   }

    public static Globals getInstance() {
        return singleton;
   } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();
    player_health=10;
    }
}
```

Now Access your Variables Using `Globals.getInstance().getData();`